# is this function integrable i.e $L^{1}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am going to use the dominated convergence theorem and in my book (Folland) we have the following def of an integrable function:

If $E\in\mathcal{M}$, f is integrable on $E$ if $\displaystyle\int_{E}|f|<\infty$.

Now let $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),m)$ be our measure space, I want to show that $e^{-x}\in L^{1}$ and $f_{n}(x)=\Bigl(1+\frac{x}{n}\Bigr)^{n}e^{-2x}\in L^{1}$

My solution

Let $E=[0,\infty)$ then $\int_{0}^{\infty}|e^{-x}|=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}dx=1<\infty$

So $e^{-x}\in L^{1}$ on $E$

will this be sufficient?

My second question is how to show that $f_{n}(x)\in L^{1}$?
This is a product of two integrable functions. Does this imply that this is also integrable function?

Comment: Being a product of two integrable functions doesn't imply being integrable. But $f_n$ is continuous, and $\lvert f_n(x)\rvert \leqslant e^{-x}$, so it is integrable, since it's measurable and bounded by an integrable function.

Comment: I get annoyed with sloppy notation like this, I'm sorry. It is very helpful to make it clear which space you're working with, e.g., $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ or $L^1([0,\infty))$. In this case I assume you're trying to prove that the function $x \mapsto e^{-x}$ $(x\in\mathbb{R})$, when restricted to $[0,\infty)$, is a function in $L^1([0,\infty))$; it's most definitely not in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$!

Comment: @Daniel: Thanks, nicely clarified.

Answer (score 4):

The product of two integrable functions is not necessarily integrable. On the other hand, since $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac xn \right)^n e^{-x} = 0$$ there is a constant $C_n$ with the property that $$\left( 1 + \frac xn \right)^n e^{-2x} \le C_n e^{-x}.$$ Thus $$\int_0^\infty \left( 1 + \frac xn \right)^n e^{-2x} \, dx < \infty.$$

Answer (score 1):

Notice this

> $$\left(  1+x/n\right)^n\leq e^x.$$